# How to upload image file in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, file-upload

I have a gridview that shows an image as part of a column. In Edit mode, I would like to let the user upload a new image file, so I'm using the FileUpload control in the edit part of the template.

When I click on update it's showing me this:

[image]

My code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    Label lb = GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("Label1") as Label;
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    FileUpload fu = row.Cells[0].FindControl("fileupload") as FileUpload;
    if (fu.HasFile)
    {
        string file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/uploadedimages/"), fu.FileName);
        fu.SaveAs(file);

        using (Ex_RepeaterEntities entities = new Ex_RepeaterEntities())
        {
            Student students = (from e1 in entities.Students
                                where e1.Id == Convert.ToInt32(lb.Text)
                                select e1).First();
            students.Images = file;
            entities.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems to be that you don't set a value for **fu** which means that it doesn't find any control named **fileupload** within **row.Cells[0]**!! Can you show where/how you get/set the **row** variable, please?

Comment: I just use row variable to find my control thats it. I found this trick on google. Before I was used this : 'FileUpload tb = GridView1.FindControl("fileupload") as FileUpload ;' but it also give me the same error

Comment: @cramopy I posted my own question answer please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got my own solution of above post. Here is code to be changed:

```
if (fileUpload.HasFile)
{
       fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("uploadedimages/" + fileUpload.FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching I found solution of above error by using this code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
        int RowID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
        FileUpload fileUpload = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("fileupload") as FileUpload;
        if (fileUpload.HasFile)
        {
           fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/uploadedimages/" + fileUpload.FileName));
        }
}
```

and at page.aspx:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload Image" SortExpression="Names">
     <EditItemTemplate>
          <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="fileupload" />
     </EditItemTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Image ImageUrl="~/uploadedimages/1.jpg" runat="server" ID="image" />
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

But a little problem here is to solve which is that file is not saving.